# Validating a string only numbers

Tags: c

I'm getting an error in this part of my code with the comparison between pointer and integer

```
#include<stdio.h>

int validateString(char *inStr);
int main()
{
    char *stringInput="";
    printf("Please enter a 10 digit phone number: ");
    scanf("%s",&stringInput);
    if (validateString(stringInput)== 1)
    {
        printf("%s is a valid phone number.",stringInput);
    }
    elseif (validateString(stringInput)== 0)
    {
        printf("%s is a valid phone number.",stringInput);
    }
}

int validateString(char *inStr)
{
    int i;
    int length= strlen(inStr);
    for (i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(!(inStr[i]>= '0' && inStr <= '9' || inStr[i]== ' '))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        elseif(length>=12)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

What should I change about the pointer passing through in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some pace to place the string in

i.e

```
char *stringInput="";
```

should be

```
char stringInput[20];
```

Then

```
scanf("%s",stringInput);
```

Did not even get to the point where `elseif` will not compile

Answer (score 1):

***Change*** this from :  *(see in-line comments to explain changes...)*

```
        char *stringInput="";//creates no space for user input
        printf("Please enter a 10 digit phone number: ");
        scanf("%s",&stringInput); //`stringInput` already pointer (`char *`), does not require `&`.
```

To

```
        char stringInput[20];//for additional space in case user enters more than 10
        printf("Please enter a 10 digit phone number: ");
        scanf("%s",stringInput);//do not use `&` for string
```